# How can I safely make a float *x into a const float *const *y?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have a function `audioReceived (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels)` inside of which I want to call a function from a library that needs `const float *const *inputBuffers`.

Obviously casting `const float *const *inputBuffers = (const float* const*)input;` compiles but is a terrible idea, crashes the program, kills kittens, etc. Nobody ever needs to modify the original `float* input`, it's incoming audio data that's being processed.

How do I do it the right way?

**EDIT: Here's some more code.** `audioReceived` is:

```
void testApp::audioReceived (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels){ 

     Vamp::RealTime rt = Vamp::RealTime::fromMilliseconds(ofGetSystemTime());
     float const *const tmp[] = { input, 0 };    
     Vamp::Plugin::FeatureSet fs = myPlugin->process(tmp, rt);
 }
```

Library function `process` is virtually defined in base class:

```
 /**
 * Process a single block of input data.
 * 
 * If the plugin's inputDomain is TimeDomain, inputBuffers will
 * point to one array of floats per input channel, and each of
 * these arrays will contain blockSize consecutive audio samples
 * (the host will zero-pad as necessary).  The timestamp in this
 * case will be the real time in seconds of the start of the
 * supplied block of samples.
 *
 * If the plugin's inputDomain is FrequencyDomain, inputBuffers
 * will point to one array of floats per input channel, and each
 * of these arrays will contain blockSize/2+1 consecutive pairs of
 * real and imaginary component floats corresponding to bins
 * 0..(blockSize/2) of the FFT output.  That is, bin 0 (the first
 * pair of floats) contains the DC output, up to bin blockSize/2
 * which contains the Nyquist-frequency output.  There will
 * therefore be blockSize+2 floats per channel in total.  The
 * timestamp will be the real time in seconds of the centre of the
 * FFT input window (i.e. the very first block passed to process
 * might contain the FFT of half a block of zero samples and the
 * first half-block of the actual data, with a timestamp of zero).
 *
 * Return any features that have become available after this
 * process call.  (These do not necessarily have to fall within
 * the process block, except for OneSamplePerStep outputs.)
 */
virtual FeatureSet process(const float *const *inputBuffers,
               RealTime timestamp) = 0;
```

and here in the actual header:

```
FeatureSet process(const float *const *inputBuffers, Vamp::RealTime timestamp);
```

I think the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` may be stemming from the library function wanting a zero-padded array, and my not giving it one. (a) Does that sound reasonable, and (b) If so, is it time to ask a different SO question?

Thanks all for your help so far, it's very enlightening/clarifying/educational/interesting.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You start with a pointer-to-float, and you want to get out of it a pointer-to-pointer-to-float with lots of constness bunged in. Huh?

Comment: Why does this even have a `c++` tag? Isn't it a pure C question?

Comment: To be honest, when it comes to the `const`s I'm asking "Huh?" as well-- but it's what the feature-extraction library wants and I'm trying to start by giving it what it wants before I start trying to rewrite the library. (Which would probably just lead to more confusion, anyway; my working assumption is that the guy who wrote that code knows a bit more than me-- though perhaps not more than some of you.)

Comment: @sbi: It applies in C++ too, and if he's compiling in C++, then the floor is open to solutions that are valid in C++ but not in C.

Comment: @ickydog: And you're absolutely sure that it's `const float* const*` (better written `float const* const*`)? Not just `float const* const`? Are you sure that you have interpreted correctly what the input should be to the library function? What does the documentation say?

Comment: "inputBuffers will point to one array of floats per input channel" in the comments before the function def. One input channel here. So I'm interpreting from an array of floats (`float * input`) to an array containing said array (`float const *const tmp[] = { &input`, 0 }`, as below). Makes sense conceptually, but I get a compile error on the latter.

Comment: @ickydog: Post a testcase. And, how does the library know how long the array it is? Does it look for the NULL final element that Simon proposes? You _must_ check these things.

Comment: Ah, the library *is* expecting a certain (known) size of array. I'm going to check this out as it is almost definitely now the cause of the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Will post back after. Thanks all for super-fast help so far.

Comment: @Tomalak: We're talking pointer manipulation here, there's nothing C++ could do outside of C's realm. And the "applies to C++, too" argument would make 98% of all C questions apply to C++. I'd resent that.

Comment: @sbi: Your previous comment implied you believe that all C++ questions -- where the OP is writing C++ and compiling in C++, and _couldn't accept C-but-not-C++ answers_ -- should have a `c` not a `c++` tag if the existing, original code would be accepted by a C compiler.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, indeed, that's a fallacy of my previous comment. `:-x` Still, this is obviously a C library, and it is C code ickydog is writing.

Comment: @ickydog: Please direct your comments using the "@name:" syntax, so that we get notifications.

Comment: @sbi: When were namespaces and member functions added to C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantics is important here. From the parameter names, I can guess that the function you want to call accepts multiple buffers, so it wants an array of pointers to float (i.e. an array of arrays). Since you only have an array, you need to create an array that contains the original pointer, and pass that to the function.

If the function has a separate argument for the length of the array it is being passed (i.e. the number of buffers), then taking the address using the unary `&` operator and passing a length of 1 should be enough, otherwise you need to create a temporary null terminated array:

```
float const *const tmp[] = { input, 0 };
```

and pass that to the function.

Comment: Yea, I suspect something along these lines. However, without knowing, it's all just a guess! The OP should read the library documentation.

Comment: @Tomalak, I have been a good boy and read it but the docs aren't exactly clear/complete. Given that it's open-source, I hope to help with that but first I have to figure out how it works!

Comment: @ickydog: No, he meant what he wrote. You may be hitting [this](http://kera.name/articles/2009/12/a-question-on-indirect-constness/) in addition. I think we've reached the limits of what we can tell you from the limited information given.

Comment: Actually, I meant it without the `&`. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Doing `&input` should be enough for the cast itself. Note that the argument of the internal function is a pointer to pointer.

**Edit:**

To get a null terminated list of input buffers as required in your comments to the original question, you may use:

```
float const * const buffers[] = {input, 0};
```

Comment: It may be enough. That depends on the called function.

Comment: thought that might be it, but it `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`'s at runtime.

Comment: @Kevin: I realised my answer doesn't apply here (because the function takes a `const char * float *`, not a `const float **`) so I deleted it.  If @Juraj makes a null edit to his answer, I can remove my downvote.

Comment: It may not be enough if the library is expecting an array with a final element of `NULL`. Assertions here are dangerous without knowing what the library is expecting.

Comment: @Oli: I don't understand your point here. The conversion itself is correct. And I posted the answer long before the note about the required format by OP. The question was about casting, which I thing that I have answered. I may edit the answew though.

Comment: @Juraj: I agree that your answer is correct (@Tomalak's point notwithstanding).  The problem is that SO enforces a rule that you cannot change a vote more than 5 minutes after you cast it, unless the answer is edited.  If you perform any edit at all to your answer, I can remove my (erroneous) downvote!

Comment: @Oli: Edited and extended to also answer the additional question.

Answer (score 1):

```
float *
```

is not the same as

```
float **
```

so casting `input` to `inputBuffers` isn't going to work.

Generally, casting from non-const to const is implicit, you don't need to do anything special. You can't cast from const to non-const as easily. Which is logical when you think about it.

Comment: This is correct, but there are some important caveats.  You can't implicitly convert from `T**` to `const T**`, for instance.

Comment: No problem. `T**` cannot be implicitly converted to `T const**` but can be converted to `T const* const*`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it a `float **`, i.e. pointer to pointers to floats. The `const`s just tell you that the function isn't going to modify any of the values being pointed to.

If you have a potentially variable number of channels `nChannels`, of `bufferSize` floats per channel, then you could set up the necessary storage with e.g.

```
float **data = new float *[nChannels];
for (int c = 0; c < nChannels; ++c) {
    data[c] = new float[bufferSize];
}
```

after which `data` is in the right format to pass to this function. (The function knows how big these things are, because you have previously provided the channel count and block size to the plugin constructor.)

Your example code shows you have a single-pointer `float *`, which suggests you might be starting with data in an interleaved format (i.e. alternating channel values within a single array). If that's the case, you will need to de-interleave into separate channels in order to pass to the `process` function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i) {
    for (int c = 0; c < nChannels; ++c) {
        data[c][i] = input[i * nChannels + c];
    }
}
myPlugin->process(data, rt);
```

Finally, don't forget to `delete[]` the member pointers as well as the double pointer afterwards.

```
for (int c = 0; c < nChannels; ++c) {
    delete[] data[c];
}
delete[] data;
```

If, on the other hand, you know that you will only ever have a single channel of data -- and you have supplied 1 as the channel count in the plugin constructor -- then you can just do an extra indirection as others have suggested:

```
myPlugin->process(&input, rt);
```

(disclosure: I wrote the code that was confusing the questioner)